# I want to create a 2m x 2m iridescent surface on concrete. Which Stack Exchange site would be appropriate for advice?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

I would like to create a large iridescent surface on an indoor concrete floor (up to 2m x 2m).

I am considering how to create a surface which is as intense and complex as possible with generally available materials and on a small budget. I am thinking about whether to smooth the concrete and/or spray it with a dark coating, what lighting would be good, whether to go for a wet or dry solution, etc.

I tried [Chemistry Stack Exchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/), reasoning that whatever the solution would be would rely heavily on whatever substances are used to create the iridescent film, but from the only two that did respond, one argued it was a phenomenon of physics.

Which might be a more appropriate Stack Exchange site where the question would fit the community better?

Comment: Did you check [Home Improvement ?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: [xkcd 435](https://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/435:_Purity)

Answer (score 12):

I would probably take a look at [Home Improvement SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com).  They do have a [concrete](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concrete) tag with many questions.

If you are doing this from a more "artistic" approach (looking at images of iridescent things certainly seems rather artistic), then perhaps the [Arts and Craft SE](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/).

As always, you should look over the help pages of the sites to make sure your question meets their guidelines prior to asking your question.